# .ToString() and .ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, tostring

I must use `.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` in every number to string conversion for example. Can I somehow override `.ToString()` so that I will get no more messages like culture in string conversion explicitly?

For example, now I have to change every

```
myNumValue.Count.ToString();
```

to

```
myNumValue.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of this rule is to make an *explicit* choice of culture for every formatting and parsing operation.  If you try to systematically swap implementations to "trick" the rule, you'll simply end up sweeping potential problems under the rug.  As suggested by Lonli-Lokli, you may want to consider using extension methods if you don't like reading `ToString` calls with a culture arguments, but you should have a distinct extension method for each culture you support.  e.g.: `ToUIString()` -> `ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` and `ToInvariantString()` -> `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: I've had some pretty interesting issues with people not specifying cultures on ToString or string.Format calls while writing custom file formats to disk. When a new colleague joined from India and Japan all kinds of issues occurred. Of course not specifying the culture lead to the two users to write out differently formatted data, which of course could not be read by the other users.

Over time I've learned to never suppress this rule or to seek a work around. I've seen too many issues caused by not doing that.

Comment: It's even worse if you go into production with code that formats or parses "common use" data using client thread cultures.  In many cases, you can't infer the intended culture from the stored data (e.g.: is 3/5/2001 the 3rd day of May or the 5th of March?), so you can't properly clean up existing data once you find an in-production localization bug.  That said, I don't necessarily enforce "raw" ToString(culture) use since I sometimes prefer using a mechanism that will allow me to swap out the culture sources.  In such cases, I would generally add a custom FxCop rule to prevent use of ToString.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't make any sense to replace `ToString()` with `ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` cause this is exactly what `ToString()` already does.

If you don't put a defined culture (maybe through a user selection) into your code simply stick to the first method.

Comment: inst default invariantCurrentCulture and not CurrentCulture

Comment: Default is CurrentCulture, that's why it creates problems when people omit it.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a message from Code Analysis, then you can disable a particular rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can create extension method, ToStringEx and call usual method with specified culture.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a ToStringInvariant and a ToStringCurrent extension methods with one override for each type to convert: int, double, decimal, etc. It is a matter of minutes with copy and paste.
DateTime can eventually be handled the same way.